# How do i solve this recurrence relation using De Moivres Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Given that $a(0) = 1, a(1) = -1$, $a(n)= -4a(n-2)$ for all n>= 2, Solve the recurrence relation.

I know that the characteristic polynomial is $x^2+4=0$, using the quadratic equation we get the two roots as +- $\sqrt{-16}/2$ which i simplified to $+-2i$

The solution to the recurrence relation will be in the form

$a(n) = A(0+-2i)^n+B(0+-2i)^n$

how can I solve this recurrence? My prof used De Moivres Theorem to solve something similar but I do not understand the theorem

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $(-2i)^n=2^n(-i)^n$; $(-i)^n=-i, -1, i, 1, -i, -1, i , 1 ...$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...$

Comment: Rather than $\pm$, write $a(n)=A(2i)^n+B(-2i)^n$. Then the initial conditions $a(0)=1$, $a(1)=-1$ give you two linear equations in the two unknowns $A,B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general method of solution, you can see [Theorem 4.2, part(3) and Example 4.4(c)](http://www.eco.uc3m.es/docencia/matavanzadas/English/apuntesyejercicios/Chapter2-Part2.pdf)

The characteristic equation is $r^2 + 4 = 0$ with solutions

$r = \pm ~i~2$

which means

$\rho = 2$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Hence the general solution is

$a_n = 2^n \left( A \cos {\frac{n \pi}{2}} + B \sin {\frac{n \pi}{2}}\right)$

Putting $n = 0$ in the above solution we have

$a_0 = A = 1$

Putting $n = 1$ in the above solution we have

$a_1 = 2^1 \left( A \cos {\frac{1 \pi}{2}} + B \sin {\frac{1 \pi}{2}}\right) = -1$

Notice that $\cos {\frac{\pi}{2}} = 0$

or, $a_1 = 2B = -1 \implies B = -\frac{1}{2}$

Finally

$a_n = 2^n \left( \cos {\frac{n \pi}{2}} -\frac{1}{2} \sin {\frac{n \pi}{2}}\right)$

Please let me know if you could follow all the steps.

Comment: I edited the answer a bit... Is it clear now?

Comment: This is perfect thank you for the help, really appreciate it

Comment: @KevinG Please mark one of the answers as accepted $(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark})$.